# HTML5 canvas "reset" fillStyle

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm starting to learn work with JavaScript  and HTML5's canvas.

I'm trying to draw several elements with different patterns, but I'm getting always the last setted pattern. I tried to use `save()` and `restore()` methods to store stack stats but surely I'm making a mistake somewhere, can anybody help me?

```
window.onload = function(){
    draw(100, 100, "http://www.itexto.net/devkico/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/stackoverflow-logo-250.png");
    draw(0, 0, "http://googlediscovery.com/wp-content/uploads/google-home.png");            

};

function draw(x, y, src) {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    context.save();

    var imageObj = new Image();
    imageObj.onload = function(){
        var pattern = context.createPattern(imageObj, "repeat");

        context.rect(x, y, 100, 100);

        context.fillStyle = pattern;
        context.fill();
    };
    imageObj.src = src;
    context.restore();
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`.save()` and `.restore()` are a perfectly valid way to do this.  Your issue is a classic aync error in that your `.restore()` code is being called *before* your callback.  In otherwords, this is happening:

```
context.save()
context.restore();

function(){
    context.fillStyle = pattern;
}
```

put `context.restore()` *inside* your callback function.

Comment: so you are suggesting: 
context.save(); 
imageObj.onload = function(){ (...) context.restore();}? 
i've tried, but didn't work

Comment: no, he's saying `imageObj.onload = function() { context.save(); ...; context.restore(); } `

Comment: that didn't work too. last image is being used lways as pattern.

Comment: Sorry, saw one issue and didn't notice the others :)  Try `context.fillRect(x, y, 100, 100);` instead of `context.fill()` to see if that's what you're trying to actually get.  Your `.rect()` isn't restricting the fill at all, so your 2nd image is just being drawn on top of the first one.

Answer (score -1):

The simple way in in the body do not call draw function because `window.onload` already call it. Change the `window.onload` for a function and call it from the body and that's it!

Example:

```
var joda = function()
{ 
    draw(100, 100, "http://www.itexto.net/devkico/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/stackoverflow-logo -250.png"); 
    draw(0, 0, "http://googlediscovery.com/wp-content/uploads/google-home.png"); 
}; 

<body onload="joda();">
```